# how do I do foo[bar] (partially dynamic property access) in fable?

Tags: fable-f#

I have a fairly simple javascript method

```
(props,propName,componentName) => {
    var value = props[propName];
    const getOrSpread = name =>
        props[name] || props.spread && props.spread[name];
    // remainder of function code omitted
}
```

that is working in javascript land. I'm trying to convert it to fable but either I can get it to have a definitely exists property access to `.spread` or dynamic access to `props[propName]` but not both

```
module JsxHelpers =
    type IReactProps =
        abstract member spread : obj


let isfuncOrNullPropType (props:IReactProps) (propName:string) componentName =
        let propsO :obj = box props
        let value:obj = propsO?propName

        let valueAttempt2:obj = (box props)?(propName)
        // rest of translation not attempted yet
        value
```

where if props is defined as IReactProps, then .spread works, but neither of the two possible `let value lines` compile.
or props is defined as `obj` and it says `This expression was expected to have type 'obj' but here has type ''a -> obj'

even the simplest object from the documentation doesn't appear to compile:

```
let isfuncOrNullPropType (props:obj) (propName:string) =
    let value2:obj = props?propName
    value2
```

using `"fable-core": "^1.0.0-narumi-905"`

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to put the prop name in parentheses according to the documentation.  The compiler error you're getting is because `props?(propName)` returns type `'a -> obj`.  Apparently, the dynamic (`?`) operator returns an `Applicable`, and from the fable source:

```
/// DO NOT USE: Internal type for Fable dynamic operations
type Applicable = obj->obj
```

Perhaps try:

```
let value : obj = unbox<obj> (props?(propName))
```